# Undoing one's activity other than voting, deleting a question or a comment

Tags: feature-request, editing

Today I've "rejected" an edit to a question, but came back to it later only to realize that the reason I did that wasn't right.  I would like to withdraw my vote, but I cannot do it.  The same, I presume, happens with other similar activities.  (It took me more than a year to find out how to withdraw my vote on a question without downvoting it, so maybe there is a way, just not the one easy to discover, in which case, please treat this question as a request to make this functionality more obvious).

Comment: I don't think you can revert what you did, but you can submit the same edit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If the edit was applied even though you voted against it, there is nothing to revert, is there?

If the edit was rejected eventually, that can mean that some other reviewers voted to reject it. If you *really* believe that the edit was necessary, you can always apply it yourself, but you will then be bypassing the other reviewers.

You can view the status of your reviews (including the eventual action that was taken, and what other reviewers voted) by clicking the "recent reviews" link of the relevant review queue, then "history".

The same applies to other review activities: see if your vote had consequences. If you think these consequences should be reverted, engage the process to revert.

By the way, for voting queues (for example a close vote), your vote may have more influence than only 20% of the decision, because some people will think "*eh, 4 guys already voted to close, who am I to disagree?*". So you can be a bit less shy in starting a reopen vote if you feel that it is needed: in any case, the action will require a voting majority again.

Comment: Well, the problem with this sort of activity is that the first person gets to set the overall trend. I.e. the opinion of the first voter / editor sets a chain reaction, where others hesitate less to do the same "inspired" by example. Also, obviously it is important who made the edit, so re-doing someone else's edit isn't really going to work. Voting for reopening usually collects less votes simply because there's no novelty involved, and people are typically reluctant to change their opinions, even if they know they were wrong.

Comment: When reviewing the edit queue, you don't easily (or at all) see the other votes. People with the right to review suggested edits are also people with the right to edit, so the re-edit will definitely be not really the same. For closing/re-opening, previous votes do have an influence (even though they shouldn't ! in theory you should know what you will vote before you click the appropriate button, and not change your mind according to what is shown then), so the problem is yet different.

Comment: The thing is that in the case at hand, the harm is already done. This answer merely suggests ways to mitigate it in case it is really deemed harmful. For minor edits or shabby questions, definitely not worth the hassle.